# Bootable Usb Thumb Drive

Tags: wireless-networking, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux

I have a 'gotcha' type question. I want to make a Kali Linux bootable usb thumb drive on Mac. What would happen if I take it out after I boot into Kali? The reason I ask is because my wifi adapter I use for injection takes up 2 usb ports on my Mac! This means if I live boot and have to keep the usb plugged up, I wont be able to plug up my wifi adapter to use monitor mode because my mac only has 2 usb ports. I asked this question before and someone suggested a `permanent install`. After a google the term that came up was `dual boot`. Is this the answer I am looking for?

Comment: Can't you use a USB hub? The person you mentioned suggested to install Kali on the hard drive alongside OS X but do you really want that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use a USB hub - The person you mentioned suggested to install Kali on the hard drive alongside OS X but do you really want that? You can then plug both in.

Comment: Yea, I do. Especially since the tutorial on 'WPA2 cracking with reaver' says that doing a 'live boot' is better than running Reaver from virtual box (my current set up).

Comment: Do you think a dual boot would throw off my computers speed?

Comment: It shouldn't reduce your computer's speed. But you should first ensure that all necessary hardware works in Kali, including Wifi adapter.

Comment: Edited this since this is an answer written as a question. I'd suggest a powered USB hub in this case, unless its cause your wifi adaptor is physically wide. In that case a simple extension would do

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'll look into the USB hub. For now, what's your opinion on the dual boot?

Comment: Kali isn't really an OS you want installed on a daily use system. For that matter I wouldn't recommend using it at all until you have a firm grasp of the basics. If you do not know what a dual boot is, you should not do it, since you have the chance of messing up your system in a manner you might not have the skills to recover from

Answer (score 0):

It won't work.  From what I can see from this link, [Kali does not load itself into a RAM](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence) disk.

A permanent install is not what you are looking for unless you want to modify or wipe your current OS to install it on a hard drive - a dual boot is where you can boot to either OS, but it will require hard drive space be set aside for Kali, which I expect will become complex to solve without destroying your OSx install.

I suspect it might be to limiting for you - but have you considered running it in a VM instead ?   (For example, Virtualbox).

Comment: So the usb needs to stay plugged in after Kali starts? I already am running from VirtualBox. Have you cracked a WPA2 network using Reaver? What was your experience? The tutorial I am following suggests a live boot for using Reaver etc http://www.kalitutorials.net/2014/04/hack-wpawpa2-wps-reaver-kali-linux.html

Comment: You're saying a dual boot would wipe out my entire OSX? 

Comment: i have never cracked a WIFI network ((or used Kali for that matter, although I do use Linux very, very heavily).  The USB drve would need to stay plugged in after Kali starts if you are running off a USB.    I'm not saying a dual boot would wipe your entire OSX, I'm saying that you need to have hard drive space free to install Kali, and I don't know how you would free it up in OSx.   In Windows it can be done, but its not at all trivial. Of-course I've never used Boot Camp.  For all I know that could provide an easy way to free up space.

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely look into it and make necessary provisions before making a final decision. If it helps I already have about 10 GB free on my mac which I read was the recommended amount of space necessary for a dual boot. I'll do some more research.

Comment: @davidgo How did you conclude from the possibility of "USB persistence" to `Kali does not load itself into a RAM disk`?

Comment: A few things.  the first is implied in math - > then 3 GB image but (elsewhere) 2 gigs of ram requirement precludes a RAM Disk.  The method of peristance requires a second partition on the USBdrive, and the statement "let’s create the new partition in the empty space above our Kali Live partitions." implies - but admittedly does not totally preclude a RAM disk -  that the USB partition is live.

Comment: (Also highly indicative, but by no means definate - Its not listed at https://en.wikipedia.orgwiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM#References (although  this was not your question and I did note site it earlier) despite being a lot more ubiquitous then many distros on that list, and